# Python Selenium Webpage fill: To download data from links

Tags: python, selenium, download, autofill

I've compiled this code to perform an iteration of downloads from a webpage which has multiple download links. Once the download link is clicked, the webpage produces a webform which has to be filled and submitted for the download to start. I've tried running the code and face issue in 'try'& 'except' block code (Error: Too broad exception clause) and towards the end there is an error associated with the 'submit' (Error: method submit maybe static) both of these subsequently result in 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax '. Any suggestions / help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-msdos-program")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('http://def.com/catalog/attribute')
#This is to find the download links in the webpage one by one
i=0
while i<1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="xml (Open in a new window)"]').click()
    except:
        i=1
#Once the download link is clicked this has to fill the form for submission which fill download the file

        class FormPage(object):
            def fill_form(self, data):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "radio" and @value = "Non-commercial"]').click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "checkbox" and @value = "R&D"]').click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])

                return self

            def submit(self):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value = "Submit"]').click()
                data = {
                    'name_d': 'abc',
                    'mail_d': 'xyz@gmail.com',
                }
                FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()
                driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have two warnings and a error:

1 - "Too broad exception" this is a warning telling you that you should except espefic errors, not all of them. In your "except" line should be something like `except [TheExceptionYouAreTreating]:` an example would be `except ValueError:`. However this should not stop your code from running

2 - "Error: method submit maybe static" this is warning  telling you that the method `submit` is a static method (bassically is a method that don't use the `self` attribute) to supress this warning you can use the decorator `@staticmethod` like this

```
@staticmethod
def submit():
    ...
```

3 - "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" this is what is stopping your code from running. This is a error telling you that something is written wrong in your code. I think that may be the indentation on your class. Try this:

```
i=0
while i<1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="xml (Open in a new window)"]').click()
    except:
        i=1

#Once the download link is clicked this has to fill the form for submission which fill download the file
class FormPage(object):
    def fill_form(self, data):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "radio" and @value = "Non-commercial"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "checkbox" and @value = "R&D"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])

        return self

    def submit(self):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value = "Submit"]').click()
        data = {
            'name_d': 'abc',
            'mail_d': 'xyz@gmail.com',
        }
        FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()
        driver.quit()
```

One more thing. Those are really simple errors and warnings, you should be able to fix them by yourself by carefully reading what the error has to say. I also reccomend you reading about [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)